# Coerce all inconsistently formatted string elements of Pandas series object into type datetime.time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, exception

I have a Pandas Series object (df.Lateness) in which every element is a string but the format is not consistent:

```
0    00:01:48
1    00:07:38
2    00:04:44
3    00:12:18
4           0
5           0
6    00:01:36
7           0
8           0
9           0
```

I would like to convert these into datetime.time types where 0's represent 00:00:00 in format %H:%M:%S, but when I execute the following code:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Lateness, format = '%H:%M:%S')
```

I get two exceptions:

> TypeError: Unrecognized value type: class 'str'
>
> ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)

Is there a way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure is it suits for you, but in my opinion converting non-format values to `NaT` will be more convenient:

```
result = pd.to_datetime(lateness, format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.time
```

Result:

```
0    00:01:48
1    00:07:38
2    00:04:44
3    00:12:18
4         NaT
5         NaT
6    00:01:36
7         NaT
8         NaT
9         NaT
```

---

If you still want to convert `NaT` to `00:00:00` using `fillna`:

```
result.fillna(pd.to_datetime('00:00:00', format='%H:%M:%S').time())
```

Result:

```
0    00:01:48
1    00:07:38
2    00:04:44
3    00:12:18
4    00:00:00
5    00:00:00
6    00:01:36
7    00:00:00
8    00:00:00
9    00:00:00
```